# disable checkbox after select 4 checkboxes if there are many checkbox groups

Tags: php, jquery

I dont know how to explain my question but Im using foreach to repeat a group of checkboxes such as group of drinks and group of foods, I want to disable other checkboxes when I select 4 check boxes but the problem it is diable all check boxes in other groups
To be more clear please check the screenshot
[image]

```
 <div class="option__choices">
  @foreach($groupCustomizes as $key=>$customize)  
   <label class="control control--checkbox option__choice-name">
 <input type="checkbox" name="customizecheck" value="{{$customize->id}}" >
<div class="control__indicator"></div></label>
 @endforeach
  </div>

 $('.option__choices input').on('change', function() {
  if ($(":checkbox[name='customizecheck']:checked").length == 4)                                              
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);  
   else                                                     
   $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false); 
   });
```

Comment: it's possibile to select 2 drinks and 2 foods?

Comment: you didnt get what I want , I want to deal with every group as seperated but because it repeats them all the checkboxes will have the same names

Comment: You can create an array group with class like `<input type="checkbox" class="drink" name="customizecheck[]" value="{{$customize->id}}" >` than disable ckeckbox of that class when it's reached 4 elements

Comment: but this didnt solve the problem its the same, its disable checkboxes in the two groups???

Comment: I cant name it drink because it will name the food group with the same name, this because Im using foreach to make loop, you understand?

Comment: No, I'm sorry but I just can't understand what you want to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198427/discussion-between-ash-and-andrea-manzi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkboxes are in groups/columns so you can use jQuery to check just those checkboxes from parent div.

Here's working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lvr2c4d/

Here's fixed code:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    var $checked = $(this).parent().parent().find(':checkbox[name="customizecheck"]:checked');
    var $notChecked = $(this).parent().parent().find(':checkbox:not(:checked)');

    if ($checked.length == 4)                                           
        $notChecked.prop('disabled', true);  
    else                                                     
        $notChecked.prop('disabled', false); 
});
```

Comment: The columns in jsFiddle are horizontal. Here I've put background color so it's easier to see the parent divs https://jsfiddle.net/9Lvr2c4d/

Comment: please I want to make the checked.length dynamicly so I have in every form the value 
 <input type="text" id="maxAllowed" value="4" hidden="">

which changed in every form

Comment: can you help me to make the selection dynamicly?